# Can you always define the sum of ideals?

Tags: ideals

Let $R$ be a ring and $I_1, I_2$ be ideals. 
Then the sum of these ideals is defined as:

$I_1+I_2=\{s_1+s_2| s_1\in I_1\,\text{and}\, s_2\in I_2\}$

Is it always possible to define this sum of ideals, or just for a finite amount of ideals?

Let $\{I_k\}_{k\in K}$ be a family of ideals.
In which case can you define $\sum_{k\in K} I_k$?
Has $K$ to be finite, countable or can $K$ even be uncountable?

Since we are in a ring the addition is closed and always gives an element of $R$.
So $\sum_{k\in K} I_k$ is always well defined.

Am I right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's always possible to define sum of an arbitrary family of ideals, but in obvious sense, using finite sums of elements in the family. In particular, when $K$ it's finite you have the definition that you've mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every family $\{I_k\}_{k \in K}$, $\sum_k I_k$ is defined to be the ideal generated by $\cup_k I_k$. It is the same thing that the set of all finite sums $a_1+ \cdots + a_n$ where $a_i$ is in some $I_k$.